# Need help importing csv with first and last names to Active Directory

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory

I have a `.csv` file with the columns firstname, lastname, and employeenumber, but I am only able to import the csv into Active Directory if I add name and Displayname columns, since it completely disregards the firstname and lastname columns and I'm not sure why.

Without adding the name and Displayname columns it won't even work, and then when I do add those it works but there is no first or last name added to the accounts so it's just ignoring those columns and only taking from the name column it seems. I am using this command to import the file -

```
Import-Csv .\New-Users.csv 
    | New-ADUser -Enabled $True -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString Pass123456 -AsPlainText -force)
```

Comment: Import-CSV separates column by a delimiter which by default is a comma.  If columns are not being split than there is no comma between the columns.  Delimiters can be tab, and semicolons.  Or the data my be fixed width columns.  Just because the extension is CSV doesn't mean the person who generated the file knew what they were doing and separated the columns by a delimiter.

Comment: @jdweng The file does have commas separating each value, and it imports fine. I just mean I want to figure out how to get the first and last name columns to apply since they seem to be getting ignored, when I check the first and last names aren't there on the account. Other columns like display name work as intended.

Comment: Please dont change the premise of the question with follow up issues. Thats not how this site works. If you have a new problem then ask a new question.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yeah my bad i changed back the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likable cause of your issue is that your CSV columns don't match with [cmdlet's parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters). For example, the `firstname` column should be named `givenname` to be bound to the [`-GivenName` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-givenname) and `lastname` should be renamed to `surname` to be bound to the [`-Surname` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-surname). Changing this in your CSV should fix the immediate problem.

**The cmdlet can't determine what column should be bound to which parameter unless you name the columns properly.** See [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument) to get a better understanding of how PowerShell bounds arguments from pipeline.

Comment: That did fix the issue but now I have another. The first account in the list imports successfully but the rest of them give the error "The specified account already exists" even though they definitely don't exist.

Comment: @V_093 you need a column that determines uniqueness for the users, such as `-SamAccountName`. This next issue should be asked on a new question if any doubts. This answer only solves the question being asked.